# Composer could not find the config file: C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin

Tags: laravel, composer-php, git-bash

I cannot seem to install Laravel using the following command: `composer create-project laravel/laravel laravel-testing --prefer-dist` as it keeps throwing the following error:

```
 [InvalidArgumentException]
 Composer could not find the config file: C:\Users\Kieran\AppData\Roaming\Co
 mposer\vendor\bin
 To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file as described in
  the http://getcomposer.org/ "Getting Started" section
```

[image]

The **vendor** and **bin** folders did not exist in the below path, so I created the folders `vendor` and then `bin` inside that but still no luck:

```
C:\Users\Kieran\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I managed to fix this problem. I had to delete the `composer`environment variable. Which can be found here: `Control Panel>System>Edit the system environment variables>Environment variables>composer>delete`

After I deleted this I could run the command I wanted with out any errors and it worked as expected: `composer create-project laravel/laravel laravel-testing --prefer-dist`

Comment: After the delete, close cmd and reopen, then run the command again

Answer (score -2):

Enter `composer` in your "cmd".

You will get all the command line there. All you have to do is type
`composer init`.

And the rest you can set up just as explained in the instructions.